# How to pass Landsat data(as R script) as input (band.tf) to java

Tags: java, r, tiff, rscript, landsat

I have seen commands in Landsat8 package of R I can able to run them in R console now I want to pass these commands in R-script from java.

I want to pass landsat8 commands like reflcon(),reclassify() to R from java.I don't know how to pass landsat8 bands as input to R from java? Can you suggest any better links for examples

```
    package pkg;

    import org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException;
    import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;
    import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException;

    public class Tempuser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    RConnection connection = null;

    try {

        connection = new RConnection();
        connection.eval("source('D:\\\\MyScript.R')");
        int num1=10;
        int num2=20;
        int sum=connection.eval("myAdd("+num1+","+num2+")").asInteger();
        System.out.println("The sum is=" + sum);


    } 
    catch (RserveException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (REXPMismatchException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    }


     <b> R script </b>
      myAdd=function(x,y)
       {
           sum=x+y
           return(sum)
       }
```

Comment: One link: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r

Comment: I have seen some of them but i didn't get any , can you suggest some more details sir

Comment: Yes, post a **clear** question there, with a **minimal reproducible example**, i.e. some data sample and code.

Comment: is there any solution or else tell me the alternative